# Compiled Javascript not Working in Production Mode

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am building an app on my local machine. When I precompile and run it in production mode, the compiled javascript stops working. Specifically, I have javascript in one coffeescript file and application.js, both in the assets folder. All other javascript (i.e. jquery in ajax forms, etc) continues to work, which is why I think it must have to do with compilation.

Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require jquery-ui/dialog
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require dresssed
//= require raphael
//= require morris
//= require best_in_place
//= require_tree .

$('.label-stock-health').popover({ html : true});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if ($('.search-bar').length){
      if($(".search-bar").is(":visible")) {

      } else {
        $(".search-bar").show();
        $("#q_name_cont").focus();
      }
    }

});

$("#spinner").hide();

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#spinner").fadeIn('slow');
  }).ajaxStop(function() {
      $("#spinner").hide();
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".show-search").click(function(){
        if ($('.search-bar').length){
            $(".search-bar").toggle();
          }
        });
        $(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

This functionality still works in development mode. Additionally, if I hard code the javascript into my layout template, it will work. But without the hardcoding, it does not.

Any advice on what might be the culprit?  If not , what is the best way to go about debugging this?

UPDATE #1
The only two errors I am seeing in the Javascript console of Chrome developer tools are posted below. They also show on my localhost development instance, where my javascript functionality is working in full.

> Uncaught Google Maps API is required. Please register the following
>   JavaScript library
>   http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true.(anonymous function) @
>   application-6ab26aa5fc5d647a3b5543af7c9838a6.js:9t.(anonymous
>   function) @
>   application-6ab26aa5fc5d647a3b5543af7c9838a6.js:9(anonymous function)
>   @ application-6ab26aa5fc5d647a3b5543af7c9838a6.js:9 variants:565 GET
>   http://www.example.com/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: Step 1: Provide us with an error.

Comment: Hi, I posted the errors I see in chrome developer tools above, but neither are relevant to the non-working functionality. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What specifically has stopped working? There is a lot of guessing with your question. Be as specific as you can and I'm sure you'll get the help you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, I added more details above including the code that no longer works. Thank you

Comment: Did you try RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Comment: Or you could put  gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production and deploy your code again

Comment: You can get the server log using heroku logs -n <<line count>> -a <<app name>>. This should give you any server side error.

Comment: I tried precompile, it did not resolve the issue. Also I tried adding rails_12factor gem but it did not change anything. Finally, I ran heroku logs to check for server side errors and found nothing except for a routing error on a styling file (I get the same error on my localhost and the jquery works fine there):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"):

Answer (score 0):

I did wrote to you in upwork.com how ever here it is... If it is working in local host but when uploaded online stops working than it is permissions problem. I have encounter same problems in godady and blue host. Try playing with permissions. For (on blue host) worked permissions to be set at 5 5 4. or 5 5 5 I did not remember correctly. How ever delete all and reupload with new permissions once you figure out what they should be.

Comment: It seems that the javascript is getting served to the page, therefore I am not sure this is relevant ( I don't see any 404 or other errors in the Chrome Javascript console).

Comment: (anonymous function) usually fails because of permissions, at least in my experience. Just try it, fix permissions for java script file, and the ones that are using it, including the one that is addressed via the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

The culprit here is the popover line, you will need to include the popover plugin if you want to use it. Comment it out and deploy your code, it will start working again.

Comment: I tried commenting out all instances of popover line but it did not resolve the issue. Anyhow, I believe the popover functionality is included via dresssed, which is a bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've just sent you a message on upwork as well, but you should check if removing turbolinks from your application.js files resolves the issue:

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks ** remove this line as turbolinks interferes with javascript occasionally.
 //= require_tree .
```

Comment: Thanks but I removed that a long time ago. Any other ideas?

Comment: Think the problem may be with how your assets are compiled, if not a simple mistake being somewhere hidden in all your JS. Have you tried playing around with DevTools console in Chrome, and seeing if jQuery is loading properly?  Or as someone else has expressed, have you bundled your assets in production? ie. heroku run rake assets:precompile

Comment: I did bundle my assets in production and still not working. Oddly enough, if I try typing javascript:$(".search-bar").show(); into my browser the function still does not work, but there are elements of jquery that ARE working. For example, I have some remote forms that call on .js.erb files and those are working correctly. Could this be a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Please include another file name custom.js and updated

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
       $("#spinner").fadeIn('slow');
 });
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
     $("#spinner").hide();
 });
```

Comment: What is the reason behind this? What would be the difference between application.js and custom.js?

Comment: some time heroku missing the lines below the tree so that it is better way to create another js. 
If you see the first line of error, you will be missing something like colon or either brackets.

Comment: Please paste heroku errors here where you get it. I'll provide you exact answer on it. I also face this type errors many time while deployment on heroku.